# Circles drawn on Legs of Right Angled Traingle

Tags: geometry, circles

*$\triangle ABC$ is a right angled triangle with $\angle ABC = {90}^{\circ}$. A circle $C_1$ is drawn with $AB$ as diameter, and another circle $C_2$ is drawn with $BC$ as diameter. The circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ meet at the points $B$ and $P$. If $AB=5$, $BC = 12$, find $BP$.*

I did a proper construction, and it seemed that $\angle APB = 90$, so assuming the same I carried the solution, and found $BP$ to be $\frac {60}{13}$, which is the correct answer.
But why is $\angle APB$ right?
Is there any alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem). In short: Since $A,B,P$ lie on the circle with $AB$ as diameter it follows that the angle $\angle APB$ must be a right angle. I think using this fact is the most straightforward approach.